# How to get a date object with tomorrow's date and specific time in UTC using MomentJS?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I'm trying to get a date object with tomorrow's date, at 08:00:00 AM.
I tried this, but it just returns tomorrow's date, but at the local 08:00AM time and not in UTC.

```
var tomorrow = moment(new Date()).add(1,'days');
tomorrow.set('hour', 8);
tomorrow.set('minute', 0);
tomorrow.set('second', 0);
```

Is there a way to get that datetime object in UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to call [`.utc()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) function of that object.

```js
var tomorrow = moment(new Date()).add(1,'days');
tomorrow.set('hour', 8);
tomorrow.set('minute', 0);
tomorrow.set('second', 0);

console.log(tomorrow.utc());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

There's no need to use `momentjs`.

You can do it with **[JavaScript `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)** and [**`Date.UTC()` method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) like this:

```js
var d = new Date(); 
var now_utc =  Date.UTC(d.getUTCFullYear(), d.getUTCMonth(), d.getUTCDate() + 1,
 8, 0, 0);
console.log(new Date(now_utc));
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this alternative, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily enough in moment.js:

```js
var timeUtc = moment.utc().startOf('day').add(1, 'days').add(8, 'hours');
console.log("Output time: ", timeUtc.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```